# Interrupt if API call to payment processor takes over 60 seconds

Tags: java, multithreading, jersey, thread-safety

I'm integrating with a payments processor and am trying to deal with the scenario where:

- user clicks pay and a request is made to our server
- our server makes a request to the payment processor
- there is a significant delay on the payment processor side
- after a certain threshold e.g. 60 seconds, we alert the user that their payment was unsuccessful
- after 70 seconds the payment processor returns a successful response.

So I need to start an API call to the payment processor from within the HTTP call from the UI, then if it takes more than 60 seconds, end the HTTP call and return an error to the user, then if the API call to the payment processor eventually succeeds (say after 70 seconds), send an email to the admin team.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
    import javax.ws.rs.client.*;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    ...

    boolean overThreshold = false;
    int timeout = 60; // seconds
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            overThreshold = true;
            // return a message to user here saying their payment could not be processed
        }
    };

    new Timer(true).schedule(task, timeout * 1000);

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget webTarget
            = client.target({url of payment processor});
    Invocation.Builder builder = webTarget.request()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON);

    final Response response = builder.post(Entity.json(new Gson().toJson(request)));

    if (overThreshold) {
        // send alert email here
    }
```

There are a few problems, e.g. the `run()` method has void return value, error with `overThreshold` as being accessed from a inner class. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: IMO, its a classic use case to be implemented as reactive service. You might be interested in something similar to https://blog.payara.fish/did-you-know-asynchronous-rest-requests-and-responds-with-java-ee-and-microprofile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Future.get(timeout)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) from an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) should handle this quite cleanly.

For example:

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    // ... set up builder as before ...
    Future<Response> responseFuture = executor.submit(
            () -> builder.post(Entity.json(new Gson().toJson(request))));
    try {
        Response response = responseFuture.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // return normal response here
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
        executor.submit( () -> {
            Response lateResponse = responseFuture.get();
            // send overThreshold alert email here
            // Dummy return - prefer Callable to Runnable here for exception handling
            return null;
        } );
        // return a message to user here saying their payment could not be processed
    }
```

The choice of `ExecutorService` could be tuned to fit, or equally be a shared thread pool elsewhere in the application.

Comment: Actually, just implementing this - if i return a message to the user, then `response = responseFuture.get();` will never get executed...

Comment: Good point.  If directly `return`ing the message (as opposed to writing to a response stream), the simplest way would be to make the followup async.  The wait for the `get()` and subsequent sending of the overThreshold alert can then happen when they're ready.  The answer has been updated on these lines.  The other possibility would be to re-check if a response was sent back in the first block, after the `builder.post()`.  This is more efficient for thread counts in the failure case, but would need a bit more shared state and/or synchronization to communicate between the two threads.

Comment: Is it possible to complete the logic of the code you provide through `CompletableFuture` in jdk, which I've tried but couldn't find a way to do